# What exactly is changed in Linphone ios client source to comply with apple appstore ipV6 network support

Tags: ios, xcode, linphone

As you know already from june 1st Apple is testing applications in iPv6 network only . If the application is not supporting ipV6 network then they are rejecting the application .

I have a linphone iOS client cloned from Git and customised in last year .
Linphone has updated their code to comply with IPv6 fully recently .

Can someone  tell me how can I find and push IPv6 fixes  only to my downloaded linphone source . So this way I can avoid downloading complete linphone source and  rework  on my customised GUI and code .

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't how much this will help you out.
But I hope that if you just download latest source code and go th'r it for following changes, then it will help you updating your existing linphone-clone project:

[IPv6 changes commited](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/commit/a87ad118bb97362951cb383a646ffbba1b212546)
and
[Classes/LinphoneCoreSettingsStore.m changes commited](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/search?p=2&q=ipv6&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: Thanks , But it didnt work . I think something has been changed in  ortp and belle-sip stack too  . I am going through  the code changes

Comment: @Srav Did you found solution for this?

Comment: Hi sory for the late response . Yes downloaded latest build and compiled it .Tested in IPv6 wifi  its working well . You may  need a  sip account  on IPV6 SIP server .

Comment: @Srav Hi, Were you able to run the old version by making changes from the link above in the Answer. Or did you have to upgrade the SDK or do anything else to make it work.

Comment: @Srav I am using an  older version of source code. Can you please help me with the steps to run my older Linphone code to work on IPv6 Server. Can you also suggest some free SIP account which support IPv6